# JavaScript function not posting

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript function that should remove a table row from a PHP page. My question is what am I missing to make this post to my PHP page.

the line clicked to do the remove

```
echo '<td align="right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="abc" onClick="remove(id)"></i></td>';
```

the javascript:

```
function remove(id){    
        var rem = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove the id ' + id + '?');
        if (rem == true){
            alert(id); //just to see if my data is making it this far, it is
            $.ajax({
                data: 'id' + id,
                url: 'pages/ini.php',
                method: 'POST',
                success: function(msg){
                    alert('Data entered!');
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
   }
```

the php page:

```
    $test = $_POST['id'];
```

But all that it is return is an empty value. I tried to display it and all I got was empty data, or when I'd do `echo $test;` Id get a blank page with no console errors

Comment: How are you gonna see this as soon as you hit success you alert then reload.... Does the *data entered* show at all?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile on the php page it writes to a text file also, so when I open the text file it is blank

Comment: `onClick="remove(id)"` ...i'm assuming you don't have a variable set in javascript called `id` and therefore you're probably getting a variable undefined error in the console. it helps to check to console for errors.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. see last line of my question...

Comment: your code is reloading the page and therefore clearing the console. comment out the line that refreshes the page and then see what's in the console.

Comment: `data: 'id' + id` makes little sense either, even if you passed an actual numeric id parameter to your function, this would still result in `data: 'id123'` only, and that is likely not what you wand to send. You either want to pass a string of name=value pairs separated by &, or use an object in the first place.

Comment: Commented out and tried again, still no errors in the console. It alerts it correctly (right after the confirm) so I am not sure whats going on with it.

Comment: Focus on the two problems noted in these comments: 1: the "id" in "remove(id)" doesn't do what you think it does. 2: "'id'+id" doesn't do what you think it does. You need to take about 20 steps back, learn how to fetch a VALUE from an element, and then learn how to properly set a post value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

through $.ajax your request getting posted but your clicked "id" of element not getting passed because you have write

```
data: 'id' + id
```

instead of

```
data: {'id' : id }
```

This will actually send clicked element "id" to your PHP Code.

Hope, this will help you.